# Bootstrap Validation

Tags: jquery

I'm using http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

I want to submit the form via ajax if there are no errors.

nothing I try seems to work

Check for errors

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#edit_profile input").jqBootstrapValidation({
submitSuccess: function($form, event) { 
event.preventDefault();
}
});

});
```

I've tried

```
$(function() {

  $('form[id="edit_profile"]').find('input,select,textarea').not('[type=submit]').jqBootstrapValidation({

 preventSubmit: false,
 submitSuccess: function (form, event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#send').click();
 },
 submitError: function (form, event, errors) {
     event.preventDefault();
     }
 });

});
```

## send .click submits the ajax form. The form still submits even when there are errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this -

```
submitError: function (form, event, errors) {
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
     }
```

or

Add a if statement within the submitSuccess: to catch errors and return false on that case.